# Adding user inputs to cmd run path in perl scripting

Tags: perl

I am trying to read the number of lines in a .list file but the .list file is deep inside a folder. after which i will need to upload the data using CURL. my codes are as above:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $pname
printf "Enter project name: "
$pname = <STDIN>;
chomp $pname

filepath = /filebig/filemedium/filesmall/data.list"";
filefinalpath = $filename$filepath";

chdir $filepath or warn  "Can't chdir to $filepath: $!";
my $total_lines;
if (-e $filepath) { 
    open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
    $total_lines = grep { not /^$|^\s*#/ } <$fh>; 
system "curl "httpwebsitehere" -H"Atuhorization code" -d'{"time" : $epoch, "projectname": $pname}'";
}
```

my codes are definetly wrong, but my idea is lets say a user inputs the front part, it adds on to the $fileaddpath to chdir into the final folder. for example user keys in project/user123/folder1 . This is then combined with `filepath = /filebig/filemedium/filesmall/data.list` To get a final output of

cd `project/user123/folder1/filebig/filemedium/filesmall/data.list`

is the  `system "curl "httpwebsitehere" -H"Atuhorization code" -d'{"time" : $epoch, "projectname": $pname}'";` correct?

Comment: sorry to say that your question is not clear ... where is bottom method

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: @Tanimreja hiee what do you mean by the bottom method . this is result 1 and 2 , i want to sent from 1 to 2

Comment: @sihao when i click submit , the app crash

Comment: post the logs of the crash, its hard to tell whats the problem without it

Comment: @sihao can you email me so i can show u my codes , because there is alot , wenhan999@hotmail.com

Comment: its not so much of what your code does, its about what the error says. remove the part about your situation about the question and i am sure there is plenty of space to post the logs

Comment: at com.example.android.cardemulation.activityresult1$1.onClick(activityresult1.java:61)

Comment: but there is nothing wrong with the codes

Comment: and yeah, do remove your email from the comments. you wouldn't want everyone to have your email

Comment: please post the whole log, as an edit to the question. you can find an edit button at the bottom of the question

Comment: @sihao this is just a subemail , i already have lots of spams haha

Comment: it will be a really useful skill to learn to read your logs
do notice this line: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.android.cardemulation, PID: 22322 java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "" at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)

Comment: @sihao i'm really a beginner so i dont know how to read this , like i dont understand what it is trying to tell me

Comment: 1 of those `integer` that you `parse` don't have correct format,

Comment: @NguyenQuangAnh can u email me so i can show u the codes? .. please i really dont know how to change

Comment: its working now , but i cannot let it display the money

Comment: @WenhanXiao Please do not vandalize your own post. Even after a question gets answered, it is still useful for future visitors. You do not have the permission to deface your own posts. Further attempts to do so will either result in the post being locked or you recieving a suspension.

Comment: @Magisch i didnt want to do that , but i am  not allowed to post anymore questions especially when u dislike my post

Comment: @WenhanXiao you need to improve your existing questions then without changing their meaning. I've done what I can with this one.

Comment: @WenhanXiao The only way of getting out of that is by improving your existing questions-

Answer (score 3):

According to your logs,

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "" at 
java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138) at 
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358) at 
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
```

What it is trying to tell you in layman terms is,

- There is a string that you are trying parse in your code that is an empty string "" instead of a number. We can't do it, please go resolve it.

To resolve such issues, you can implement your checks in several ways

- Catch the exception and tell the user the number is not valid
- Put a default input such that even if the user does not select anything, the default value is used

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

**If I am not mistaken, the probability of your error here is rather high.**

- Comment out the codes from and onwards.

  ```
  int sum = Integer.parseInt(adapter.getQuantity()[0])*Integer.parseInt(cost[0]) +
              Integer.parseInt(adapter.getQuantity()[1])*Integer.parseInt(cost[1]) +
              Integer.parseInt(adapter.getQuantity()[2])*Integer.parseInt(cost[2]) +
              Integer.parseInt(adapter.getQuantity()[3])*Integer.parseInt(cost[3]);
  ```
- Print out each value before parsing, you will figure out which is wrong

  ```
  eg. Log.d("LOG_TAG", "cost0: " + cost[0]);
  ```

Comment: it helps , but i dont know how to change it .. T-T can u please help me ?

Comment: sihao , i have no idea what you are trying to tell me , sorry for being a burden , but i only started android studio 2weeks ago from scratch , can you kindly help me change it , i share it with u on google drive and i can understand after u change it

Comment: i would love to help, but i believe you can learn better when you try it out yourself, i will guide you from here. 

add these lines before your int sum = Integer... 

eg. Log.d("LOG_TAG", "cost0: " + cost[0]);
eg. Log.d("LOG_TAG", "cost1: " + cost[1]);
eg. Log.d("LOG_TAG", "cost2: " + cost[2]);
eg. Log.d("LOG_TAG", "cost3: " + cost[3]);

it will still crash, but from the logs, there should be some new things

Comment: i need to show my 'teacher' by today , because i already stuck here for a week

Comment: i will help you as much as possible, even if you share google docs with me, i wouldn't be able to set it up and run it. do try what i say, and see if it works

Comment: read the error message dude.. i suppose it says unable to find Log or something. You need to import the class

Comment: i dont know what is log what is class , dont even know how to import

Comment: add import java.util.Log in the first few lines of your class, you will see similar ones there

Comment: yeah it won't work, but it is suppose to help you figure out whats wrong

Comment: to be honest, i don't have any android development tools installed right now

Comment: can u download it and help me T-T . because i really need to get it done

Comment: really sorry... i am not with my computer.. the best i can help, is when you help yourself. understand and proceed, you will learn better

Comment: yeah sure . i edited the codes , can u check and see why i cannot display

Comment: Look at this error
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:923) at com.example.android.cardemulation.activityresult2.onCreate(activityresult2.java:33)

Comment: this means that at your activityresult2 class, line 33, you tried to make an Integer into a String which is not valid

Comment: i have no idea which is your line 33. i suppose your assignment submission is over. you should learn the basics before attempting to work on this project. it seems that you require a little more before you can do so.